# Find the actual page opened from the URL in the asp.net

Tags: asp.net, url, url-rewriting

HI so i keep running across websites which when looked through or searched (using their own search function) return's a static URL ie.) `?id=16` or `default.aspx` no mater what page of the website you visit after the search has been performed.   This becomes a problem when i want to go directly to a post/page within one of these sites so i'm wondering. If anyone knows How could i  actually find out what the absolute URL is.

So that i can navigate straight to it.  I'm not really familiar with coding but have tried looking in the page source but i wasn't really able to gleam anything from there.

Comment: It will be great if you can clear your grammar little more in the questions and apply the formatting to highlight the relevant things.

Answer (score 0):

The basics around asp.net urls: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/142013/There-is-something-about-Paths-for-Asp-net-beginne

It all really depends on what you're trying to find, as far as finding a backway to locate a absolute path, is highly doubtful.  If the owner of the site(most blogs) want you to have a perma link to a page, they use url-rewriting for putting things in the URI like title page and such.  Alot of MVC sites do this now.

The '?id=16' you're seeing is just a query string, a holder for other logic they are doing.